# what is private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST=1313(or1888)?

Tags: android

i m new to android please tell me about the use of this statement

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnpic;
ImageView imgTakenPic;
private static final int CAM_REQUEST=1313;
```

Comment: it is a private static field inside MainActivity  class with type of `int` and value 1313

Comment: In this context, the number is just arbitrary. You just need to make sure there is no collision with any other request properties.

Answer (score 1):

`startActitivityForRequest()` takes a request code

`onActivityResult()` uses that code to know where a result came from

The name of the variable and its value are irrelevant as long as they do not conflict with other values and are used consistently accross those methods.